# Leaks on NSString that appendformats

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks

I have lots of leaks on a NSString. I use appendformat to append strings to it.

Here's the code :

```
NSString *textedetails = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        if([dico objectForKey:@"alertSerie"] != nil)
            {[textedetails appendFormat:@"Numéro de Série: %@ \n",[dico objectForKey:@"alertSerie"]];}
        if([dico objectForKey:@"alertDate"] != nil)
            {[textedetails appendFormat:@"Date de mise en service: %@ \n",[dico objectForKey:@"alertDate"]];}
        if([dico objectForKey:@"alertCli"] != nil)
            {[textedetails appendFormat:@"Nom du client associé: %@ \n",[dico objectForKey:@"alertCli"]];}
```

...
//I put the textdetails into a UITextField and...
[textedetails release];

That code give me leaks in the first and the last line of the code above...

and the printscreen of the leaks is [HERE !!!](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/851/capturedcran20110824154.png/)

Many thanks to help me !!!

Comment: Release the string when you have finished with them.

Comment: I guess your question has been downvoted because you didn't put the code directly into the question and/or because it's a very long piece of code without any obvious effort for isolating the problem.

Comment: @CocoaFu : I make that but it doesn't do anithing (except show me the alerts).

Comment: @Yannick : I release it just after. And Codo: I edited it ;-) THANKS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *textedetails = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSMutableString *texterecap = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

both these are never released.

Try this

```
NSString *textedetails = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
NSMutableString *texterecap = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
```

or this

```
NSMutableString *textedetails = [NSMutableString string];
NSMutableString *texterecap = [NSMutableString string];
```

Comment: NSString *textedetails = [NSMutableString string]; is wrong,use: NSMutableString *textedetails = [NSMutableString string];

Comment: Ok thanks. I tried this too but it stil leak again and again on the last "appendformat" ...

Comment: Error, it leaks not right now :-D thank you (my favorite plumber is mario but you're the second :-) ) but NSString may not respond to appendFormat (it is a warning...)

Answer (score 1):

The method `appendFormat` is not directly leaking. It's just a subsequent fault because the `NSMutableString` instance is never released.

I see two locations where you create a `NSMutableString` instance with:

```
... = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

These instance have to be release somewhere.

Comment: Ok thanks. But I release it after the method and it still leak :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to release variables "textedetails" and "texterecap" right after you finish it uses.